# format html with sed

Tags: html, sed

How can I insert newlines in an  html file before each table related tag using sed?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e "s/<\\(table\\|td\\|tr\\)/\\
<\\1/gi"
```

Add other element names you are interested in.  Not 100% perfect either: it does not cater for all of HTML weirdness, but then sed will never be enough.

Comment: Don’t forget the elements THEAD, TBODY, TFOOT, CAPTION, COLGROUP, COL and TH.

Answer (score 1):

matches opening & closing tags:

```
sed "s/\(<\/\?\(table\|tr\|td\)\)/\n&/gi"
```

opening tags only:

```
sed "s/\(<\(table\|tr\|td\)\)/\n&/gi"
```

closing tags only:

```
sed "s/\(<\/\(table\|tr\|td\)\)/\n&/gi"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a basic solution

```
sed -s "s/<\(\/\?\)\(t\)/\n<\1\2/gi"
```

Not 100% perfect as it will ignore col, colgroup and catch the telytype tag but chances are you arn't using either those.